# JavaScript - Prime Number List

Tags: javascript, if-statement, for-loop, selection, primes

I am trying to learn JavaScript. I created a Prime Number List program with VB.NET. When you click "Start" Button, it divide textbox.text to textbox.text-1. Like that:

```
    dim text as new textbox
0:  text.text = textbox.text
1:  text.text = text.text - 1
    if text.text = "0" then
    listbox1.items.add(textbox1.text)
    textbox1.text = textbox1.text + 1
    goto 0
    else
    if (textbox1.text / text.text).contains(",") then
    goto 1
    end if
    end if
```

Now, I am trying to Make this with JavaScript. My JavaScript code is like that:

```
function okey(){
  var x=document.getElementById('mytext').value;
  var y=document.getElementById('mytext').value;
  looping: do {
    if (y=0){
      alert('Yup!');
    }
    else
    {
      var y=y-1;
      var s = x/y;
      if (s.indexOf(".") !== -1) 
      {
        continue looping;
      }
      else
      {
        alert('Sorry :(');
      }
   }
}
while(0);
```

I said, i am learning JavaScript. I started yesterday. 
Note: i want to add that in select (like listbox). How can i do that?
THANKS A LOT EVERYONE!

Answer (score 0):

if (s.indexOf(",") !== -1)

i think you can try with the period (".") instead of (",")

Answer (score 0):

try this

function okey(){

```
var x=document.getElementById('TextBox1').value;
var y=document.getElementById('TextBox1').value;
var flag="not prime";
if (y<2){
    flag="None";
}
looping: 
{
    var y=y-1;
var s = x/y;
if (s.toString().indexOf('.') >0) 
  {
    flag="prime";
  }
     else
{
    flag="not prime";
}
```

}

```
while(y>2 && flag!="not prime");
alert (flag);
```

}